# questions of using gdb to debug 3rd libraries

Tags: c++, gdb

I have an open-source 3rd party library with source files installed at, say, `/opt/3RD_PARTY_LIBRARY/src/`. When I debug the my program using this library, and step into a function defined in `/opt/3RD_PARTY_LIBRARY/src/a.cpp`, gdb shows that the function is executing within some file `/tmp/build/3RD_PARTY_LIBRARY-VERSION.x.x/opt/3RD_PARTY_LIBRARY/src/a.cpp` instead of the normal one `/opt/3RD_PARTY_LIBRARY/src/a.cpp`.

Can someone explain how this occurs? Is this caused by gdb or the 3rd party library?

Answer (score 0):

At compilation time, GCC records current directory and the (usually relative) file name, and puts this into debug info for the object file.

When debugging, GDB concatenates the two together, and looks for the sources there.

From the symptoms you've described, the third-party library was built in `/tmp/build/3RD_PARTY_LIBRARY-VERSION.x.x/opt/3RD_PARTY_LIBRARY/src` directory (not an unusual thing to do).

To work around this, the easiest solution is to tell GDB where the sources are now with the `directory` command: `directory /opt/3RD_PARTY_LIBRARY/src` should do it.

Alternatively, this should work as well:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/build/3RD_PARTY_LIBRARY-VERSION.x.x/opt/3RD_PARTY_LIBRARY
ln -s /opt/3RD_PARTY_LIBRARY/src /tmp/build/3RD_PARTY_LIBRARY-VERSION.x.x/opt/3RD_PARTY_LIBRARY
```